# Dealing with Firebase childDeleted and childModified observers Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

In my app I have set observers for `childAdded`, `childDeleted` and `childModified` on the  Firebase database nodes of interest to keep track of them and modify my `CoreData` device database accordingly. I just realised that if a `childDeleted` or `childModified` happens when a device is not online, it won't get notified of those events when it goes online again. As it is the normal expected behaviour as understood, I thought of a workaround as so: when I trigger deletion an entry on Firebase node, I will create an entry of the respective "deleted" node. So a `childAdded` event will be triggered when device gets back online and perform the logic that is now performed by the `childDeleted` observer. This way I won't observe any `childDeleted` events. 
So my question is: am I misusing Firebase observers ,and `childDeleted` should be communicated anyway when the device gets back online, or this kind of situation is actually the way it is supposed to work? What kind of solutions did you implement in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database synchronizes the state of the data on the server with any connected clients. Whenever a client (re)connects, Firebase makes sure that client has the current state of the data. As you've discovered Firebase explicitly *does not* synchronize state changes.

If you want to synchronize state changes, you should store precisely those state changes in the database. Because then those changes becomes the data that Firebase synchronizes.

So your solution is fine, and is in fact the idiomatic way to handle this requirement.

Comment: I should have thought of this, as  once the observer gets attached it first download the whole node, and then just new entries as they get added until detached. This  non checkin  last known state against actual state dough (which I took for granted..) makes `childDeleted`and `childModified`pretty useless. At least in my case I ain't gonna use them anymore, and in just about any other case I could think of. How do you feel about it?  I'm starting thinking about turning away from Firebase and just set my own physical Db instead..  
Will see.. thanks Frank to be always here helping out .

Comment: If you store the state changes, it's fairly common to only have a `child_added` listener. I see/have lots of cases where the node with state changes is just a queue, where you process each state change and then remove it. In that case, only handling `child_added` is normal.